# Java: access to the constants in an enumeration (enum)

Tags: java, enums, constants

reading the SCJP book, I've found something like this in the chapter 1 "self-test" :

```
enum Animals {
    DOG("woof"), CAT("meow"), FISH("burble");
    String sound;
    Animals(String s) { sound = s; }
}

class TestEnum {      
    static Animals a; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                     
        System.out.println(a.DOG.sound + " " + a.FISH.sound);   

        // the following line is from me
        System.out.println(Animals.DOG.sound + " " + Animals.FISH.sound);
    }
}
```

Note: the code compile fine.
What I don't understand is why we can access the DOG, CAT or FISH constants from the variable `a`. I thought (and it is also written in the book) that the DOG, FISH, CAT being constants are implemented in a way similar to `public static final Animals DOG = new Animals(1);`
So if they really are static why can we access them from `a` ?
The last line is the way I am familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing  `a.DOG` is the same as writing `Animal.DOG`. That is, the compiler will replace the variable with its compile time type Animal. It is considered bad code since it hides the fact that it relies on the compile time type instead of the dynamic type of `a`.

Comment: `a.DOG` differs from animal dog that `a` MUST NOT be null.

Comment: @bestsss the enum values are static so it does not depend on the value of a, running it with a == null works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Although this works, don't do it like that. Use enums with `Animal.DOG`, `Animal.CAT`, etc.

What the above does is declare an object of the enum type, and reference the static `DOG` on it. The compiler knows the type of `a`, and knows that you want `Animal.DOG`. But this kills readability.

I believe the purpose of this is to shorten the usage of enums. `a.DOG` instead of `Animal.DOG`. If you really want to shorten it, you can use `import static fqn.of.Animal` and then use simply `DOG`.

Comment: Or the purpose is that you don't get your Java Certfication... :-(

Comment: +1 for the _import static_ For some reason I only use it in junit tests (import static junit.assertEquals or mock) but it would work with enums also :)

Comment: @xtraneon - me too. Even in tests I tend to avoid static imports. But anyway, that's the official option for shorter code. No ugly hacks.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* access statics from an instance, but it's really bad taste as statics aren't as much bound to an instance as bound to the class.

Whatever the book says, don't use statics that way. And if you run checkstyle and the like, they warn about it too :)

BTW a is null in your example. Does it get initialized somewhere?

**EDIT**

I know the compiler knows what a.DOG is bound to, as statics can't be overridden. It does not need *a* to determine the call, only the compile-time type of *a*, which it has.

I also know that the example works even though *a* is *null* (I tried so I know:).

But I still think it's weird you can get stuff from *null*. And it's confusing:

```
Animals a = null;
System.out.println(a.DOG); // OK
a.doSomething(); // NullPointerException
```

When I would be debugging the NPE I would assume that *a* can't be null as the *println* worked fine. Confusing.

Ah well, Java. If you think you've seen it all you get something else again :)

Comment: Because the code accesses a static field it uses the type of the object reference rather than the value of an instance, so it doesn't matter that it a null. That's part of the weirdness of the example.

Comment: The book don't say to code that way. It's just a question at the end of the first chapter which I answered wrong cause I didn't know we could use a.SOMETHING. I understand it's bad pratice.

Comment: @florian To me it's confusing you can get something out of a _null_ _a_ :)

Comment: I think the "magic" is that it doesn't look at the value of a for a.DOG because it knows that we want to access to the enum constant so it uses the "compile time type Animal" directly. And in the book example 'a' is not even initialized, just declared.

Comment: @florian I can understand _how_ it works. It's the _why_ that baffles me. Probably a speed optimization (by design). Compile time binding is possible so why check the instance?