# Accessing the enum constants

Tags: java, enums, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: access to the constants in an enumeration (enum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206603/java-access-to-the-constants-in-an-enumeration-enum)

I was going through enums in java and I have the following query ..I have made an enum lets say..

```
 public enum Currency {
        PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
        private int value;

        private Currency(int value) {
                this.value = value;
        }
};
```

Now  suppose if I have a class A , so please show me how to access the above constants of enum from class A , an also please let me know the second approach that is  instead of enum I can also go for the interface approach what the advantages enum offer above interface..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a `getValue()` method for returning the `value` attribute of each enum constant:

```
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Currency quarter = Currency.QUARTER;
int quarterValue = quarter.getValue();  // it's 25 for the code in the question
```

Notice that the above value is different from the enum's *ordinal* value, which is accessed like this:

```
int quarterOrdinal = quarter.ordinal(); // it's  3 for the code in the question
```

Regarding the advantages of enums: they're a type-safe way of specifying that a data type has only a finite set of possible values.

Answer (score 1):

Enums gives you [type safety](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

I think the issue you are having here is, defining value as `private`. Due to which you can't access the value for the constant.

`Remove private` from the value declaration and  use

```
System.out.println(Currency.DIME.value);
```

(or) define get method for value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According Effective java Interface constant is bad practice. Interfaces are to define types not for constants.
From class A you can define variable which can hold enum value and then you can assign it any enum value

```
 Currency penny = Currency.PENNY;
```