# How to access enumeration outside the class which defines it

Tags: java

In java to access enum outside the class which it defines shall I use directly or do I have to use the class name as prefix?

Comment: Enums are just special kinds of classes, so you can have multiple classes declared in one file, you can declare Enums inside class.

Comment: @RongNK: I was asking how to access them. I have a enum test in class a. I want to access it outside of a then how should I access it?

Comment: You have to declare enum as `public ...(depend on what you want)` and then use class name as prefix when outside package.

Comment: @RongNK - It doesn't _have_ to be `public`; if its in the same package, it can have default access. You need to use the class name as a prefix even within the same package unless you import the enum. (The enum is not a member of the package; only of the enclosing class.) If the enum itself is explicitly imported, the prefix is unnecessary even when in another package.

Comment: @Ted Hopp i have commented `public ...(depend on what you want)`, i mean OP can use another scopes =)

Comment: @RongNK - Right. I just wanted to make sure that was clear to OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: access to the constants in an enumeration (enum)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206603/java-access-to-the-constants-in-an-enumeration-enum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access them directly if you import them. Otherwise you need to use the enclosing class name as a qualifier.

A.java:

```
class A {
    enum E { . . . }
    . . .
}
```

B.java (same package as A.java for this example):

```
import A.E;
class B {
    E eThing;     // works because A.E was imported
    A.E eThing2;  // always works provided A is known (in same package here)
    . . .
}
```

Of course, this answer does not address the issue of accessibility rules, which still apply. (For example, you cannot access a `private` enumeration from another class.)

If B.java is in a different package, then you don't need `import A;` to have `import A.E;`. You only need to import `A` if you need to use the (unqualified) name `A` in `B`'s code.

Subclasses of `A`, of course, inherit `A.E` because `E` is a member of `A`; they don't need any import to use `E` directly (provided access is granted).

Comment: You should include an example.

Comment: @Dibya - See my sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Declare enum alone like a class

```
public enum MyEnum{
    SOMETHING
}
```

This is the another class that access.

```
 public class AnotherClass{
        ..
        public void someMethod(){
            Sysout(MyEnum.SOMETHING);
        }
    }
```

if u do static import u can acces with the name of enum instance;

```
import static MyEnum.SOMETHING

public class MyClass{

public void method(){
 SOMETHING.name();
}
}
```

Here another possibilty like an inner class

```
  public class EnumHolder{
        public enum MyEnum{
            ENUM_INSTANCE
        }  

    }
```

and the outsider class can access here referencing the classHolder and then the enum

```
public class OutsiderClass{

    public void method(){
        Sysout(EnumHolder.MyEnum.ENUM_INSTANCE);
    }

}
```