# Java retrieving data from enums

Tags: java, enums

I work on my first java program (so this questions are relatively simple). I develop some kind of a basic roleplaying game, I work on Character's attributes.

My question are:

1. How can I retrieve data from the enums I created ( the problem is in Character constructor. I need to get values from ClassStats according to the chosen character class) ?
2. Can I store initial values of attributes for each Character Class in a better way?

```
enum ClassStats {

    Fighter(15,14,12,10,9,10), Rogue(12,12,16,14,10,10), Mage(10,10,14,16,14,10), Cleric(12,14,12,13,16,14);

    private int strength, constitution, dexterity, intelligence, wisdom, charisma;

    ClassStats(int str, int con, int dex, int intel, int wis, int cha){
        strength = str;
        constitution = con;
        dexterity = dex;
        intelligence = intel;
        wisdom = wis;
        charisma = cha;
    }

    int getStrength(){
        return strength;
    }

    int getConstitution(){
        return constitution;
    }

    int getDexterity(){
        return dexterity;
    }

    int getIntelligence(){
        return getIntelligence();
    }

    int getWisdom(){
        return wisdom;
    }

    int getCharisma(){
        return charisma;
    }

}
```

```
public class Character {

private String Name;
private String Class;
private int Level;
private long XP;
private int HP;
private int currentHp;
/*private int BAB; /*Base attack bonus*/

private int Strength;
private int Constitution;
private int Dexterity;
private int Intelligence;
private int Wisdom;
private int Charisma;

Character(String name, String chracterClass){

    Name = name;
    Class = chracterClass;
    Level = 1;
    XP = 0;
    HP = CharacterUtil.setHP(chracterClass);
    currentHp = HP;
    ClassStats cs = null;
    Strength = cs.getStrength();
    System.out.println("Strength: " + Strength);
    Constitution = cs.getConstitution();
    Dexterity = cs.getDexterity();
    Intelligence = cs.getIntelligence();
    Wisdom = cs.getWisdom();
    Charisma = cs.getCharisma();

}

}
```

Comment: Please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`). Also, it's highly recommended to avoid naming your own classes with the same names as classes in `java.lang` (e.g. `Character`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using enum, and using less primitive values and create objects for these needs. Each player class can also be a Java class (all of them extending an abstract PlayerClass)
Then Character can receive a player class in the constructor and ask it what the default attributes could be.

After this program gets larger, I would investigate the Factory design pattern.

Comment: I thought about using abstract class, but some people suggested me here to use aggregation, because a character has a character class rather than a Character is a character class. I'll check for factory design pattern. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by all means use aggregation. I mean have an abstract CharacterClass, and then each class extends it (Thief extends CharacterClass). Then a Player receives a CharacterClass in it's constructor (which will be a specific class, e.g. Rogue) and uses it to set it's initial attributes.

Answer (score 1):

A) You could just pass in the enum into the constructor.

B) Or, you can get an enum from a string value via `enumClass.valueOf(strValue)`.

C) Or, better yet, you could have a factory class to generate different default characters for you.

Additionally, these two lines don't make sense:

```
ClassStats cs = null;
Strength = cs.getStrength();
```

If you are setting it to null, then you can't invoke a method on the object. This is essentially where you could parse the enum from the string representation passed in the constructor, or if you choose option 2, you'll already have a ClassStats variable.

Comment: A) Adding enum ClassStats in the constructor is suffice ?

Comment: B) enumClass.valueOf(strValue) will give me the desired stat? where the specific character class has a role here ?

Comment: Yeah, I know that null doesn't make sense here, the ide suggested me to add it, and I forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Niminim A/B) I might have misunderstood your question, but I thought the problem was how to get the proper ClassStat enum for a given character. And the null value is due to the fact that you had an uninitialized variable - and thus, maybe why I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: The problem is how to get the data from the enum. Can you write how to retrieve the right strength value from the enum according to the chosen Character Class (as an example) ?

Comment: You already have it, though: `ClassStats c = ClassStats.Fighter;`
`System.out.println(c.getStrength());`

Comment: But you don't know that the character class is a fighter, you just have a string (let's call it characterClass) that contains the character class ( e.g "Fighter" or "Rogue" etc.). That's exactly the problem, otherwise it was very easy...

Comment: @Niminim Right - that's why I provided you w/ the snippet: `CharacterStat.valueOf("Fighter")` will output the enum CharacterStat.Fighter

Answer (score 0):

at first:

```
ClassStats cs = null;
Strength = cs.getStrength();
System.out.println("Strength: " + Strength);
Constitution = cs.getConstitution();
Dexterity = cs.getDexterity();
Intelligence = cs.getIntelligence();
Wisdom = cs.getWisdom();
Charisma = cs.getCharisma();
```

this cannot work. In the first line you set cs to "null" and than you try to access data of cs via some getters. How should you get a value from "null"?

Accessing enum values in java works like

```
YourEnum.values()[index];
```

like in [How to get Enum Value from index in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692664/how-to-get-enum-value-from-index-in-java)

or

```
YourEnum.YourValue
```

like in [Java: access to the constants in an enumeration (enum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206603/java-access-to-the-constants-in-an-enumeration-enum)

Further i would think about using a database system like MySQL to store Character-Class informations - this is much more easy to edit if your project becomes larger. The most used here is the Java Persistance API (JPA).

https://dzone.com/articles/jpa-tutorial-setting-jpa-java

Comment: Yeah, I know that null doesn't make sense here, the ide suggested me to add it, and I forgot to delete it.